in Firebase firestore. are collection names case sensitive
i want to ask in Firebase firestore. are collection names case sensitive.
I know keys and values ​​in firestore are case sensitive, but I'm not sure if collection names are.
I tried searching on google but couldn't find any article mentioning this issue.

Everything is case sensitive in Firestore.  There are, in fact, no ways to get Firestore to do anything at all with data in a case-insensitive way.  You can confirm this simply by trying it for yourself and observing the results.

Yes, in Firebase Firestore, collection names are case-sensitive. This means "Users" and "users" are considered different collections. When you’re querying or writing to a collection, make sure to use the exact same capitalization as the collection name you’ve set.
For example:
If you have 2 collections: one named 'Companies' and one named 'companies', accessing them (regardless of the language) as collection('companies') will be different from collection('Companies').

thanks. Your answer is quite similar to chatgpt. Can you give me some more reliable sources?

Check this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

If you have 2 collections: one named 'Companies' and one named 'companies', accessing them (regardless of the language) as collection('companies') will be different from collection('Companies').

Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more
